# LTSP thin client boots to a command prompt instead of a GUI

Tags: 11.10, gui, x11, edubuntu, ltsp

When I install Edubuntu 11.10 with LTSP, it installs fine. When I go to boot from the thin client it opens a terminal (looks like MS-DOS) on the thin client, but the LTSP server shows a GUI. I am new to Linux; can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, Nick and welcome to Linux and Ask Ubuntu. Come on in, the water's fine. :) This is probably due to graphics drivers, or the absence of them. Could you please post the model of your thin client?

Comment: Also helpful: run the command `startx` and post any errors.

Comment: Hi Nick. Could you provide more detailed information. You say the thin client boots to a terminal, what information does the terminal show? This can help determine if the thin client was able to pickup the kernel image and boot from it or not.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)